# How do I REALLY setup a ETH mining on Ubuntu Linux together with Jaxx? Polo: ethereumpool.co

Tags: mining, ethereum-classic

I tried to setup a ETH miner on Linux Ubuntu 16.04.2 together with Jaxx. But it was too messy. Can someone go through step by step together with me?

Comment: Hi there. What instructions were you following when you ran into a messy dead end? Asking a specific question about a particular part of the process you were following is more likely to get responses.

Comment: i tried following this tutorial.
https://www.meebey.net/posts/ethereum_gpu_mining_on_linux_howto/

Comment: Is Ethereumpool.co still up? I thought they stopped in Januari 2017...

Answer (score 2):

I myself am on the [Ethereumpool.co](https://ethereumpool.co/stats/miner/index.php?address=0x516976cE81751eBe077Ca01C57B97c9665b0e10b) pool. Also, I am on Linux 16.04, the problem you said is that you can't get it together with Jaxx?
So first off you need to install the Prerequisites.
Open a terminal and type the following **one at a time.**

```
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum-qt 
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install cpp-ethereum
```

After you do that, I suggest making a note file to keep your starting command. To connect to the pool, you want to use the command

```
ethminer -G -F http://ethereumpool.co/?miner=[HASHRATE IN MHASH]@[ADDRESS]@[OPTIONAL RIG NAME]
```

Where the hash rate is the speed, the address is your Jaxx address and your rig name. So for me it looks like this:

```
ethminer -G -F http://ethereumpool.co/?miner=19@0x516976cE81751eBe077Ca01C57B97c9665b0e10b@LLG
```

Notice, no brackets. Also the -G means GPU. **Remember, the address is your Jaxx address that you get from in-app. the ETH, not ETC**
If you have any issues comment at me.

Comment: What about for Yakkety onwards? There's no `cpp-ethereum` package since.

Comment: What binary tarball download on their GitHub download page has the miner?

Comment: The `sudo apt-get install cpp-ethereum` does not work - `cpp-ethereum` does not seem to exist... what's wrong?

Comment: @Antinous You need to download the repo now that it's different from the original. github --> ethereum cpp

Answer (score 0):

@liam W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum-qt/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum-qt/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.